# Uninstall ckeditor from Zencart v1.55e

Tags: ckeditor, uninstallation

I screwed up installing ckeditor into a new website build using zencart v1.55e.
I need to uninstall but have no idea where to begin. Anyone know of an sql patch that will delete all of the ckeditor files so I can start fresh?

Answer (score 0):

There is no sql patch for it do the following to uninstall:

1.) Disable the module by going in the admin go to Configuration -> My Store -> HTML Editor and set to "Plain Text"

2.) THEN remove the following:

- YOUR_ADMIN\includes\languages\english\extra_definitions\ckeditor.php
- YOUR_ADMIN\ckeditor.php
- Entire editors\ckeditor directory